# Image that resizes automatically covers text below it if too big

Tags: html, css

I have three things on my page: a menu to the left, a picture beside it that automatically resizes when I change my browser window and an article below the picture.

The problem is that the article does not move down as the image gets bigger.

```css
#about-wrapper{
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#box{
    border:1px solid #ba3e45;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 1vw 0 5vw;
    min-width:200px;
}

#content{
    display:inline-block;
}

.article-img{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    width:75vw;
    height:auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="about-wrapper">
        <div id="box">
          <h3 class="sub-menu">Menu 1</h3>
          <h3 class="sub-menu">Menu 2</h3>
          <h3 class="sub-menu">Menu 3</h3>
          <h3 class="sub-menu">Menu 4</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="image-wrapper">
                <img src="http://pixabay.com/get/9f1d9379e3114f892371/1428329132/banner-48962_1280.png?direct" class="article-img" width="500px" height="200px" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div id="article">
                <article><p>Lorem ipsum etc</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

How can I change it so that it keeps on looking like it does now but the article moves down if the image gets bigger?

Comment: it is because you are using position absolute on your image. Change to position relative. Should work then.

Comment: @floor thats what I thought, but without the absolute positioning the menu moves down, take a look at the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, this will get it so that the box under the image doesn't get hidden by the image.

```
#about-wrapper{
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#box{
  border:1px solid #ba3e45;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
    margin:0 1vw 0 5vw;
    min-width:200px;
}

#content{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.article-img{
  top:10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

However, you'll probably want to take a look at other options if you want a layout like:

[ #box width:200px ] [ #content width: always take up rest of page ]

once you have that, you can mess about with the image container and stuff from there, the main issue w/ your original implementation was the absolute positioning.

Comment: Maybe I did not describe the problem well enough. If you take a look at the code snippet above the text ("Lorem ipsum") is below the picture. It should move down as the size of the picture changes.
I tried your suggested solution, it displays the image across the whole browser window and hides everything underneath it.

Comment: I was thinking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pLpfyzht/ i'll adjust my answer to reflect keeping the inline-block styles